# Make textbox "ReadOnly" using an if statement in C#?

Tags: c#, if-statement, textbox, readonly

I was wondering if there was a possible code to do something like this:

```
if (textBox1.Text == "No")
{
    //some code to make textBox2 ReadOnly
}
```

Comment: yes. `textBox1.ReadOnly = true;`

Comment: WinForms? WebForms? Other? (Including this as a tag is far more useful than `if-statement` or `statement`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (textBox1.Text == "No")
{
    textBox1.Enabled=false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`TextBox.ReadOnly`](http://TextBox.ReadOnly) property if its **ASP.Net** application, For WinForm it is

If its **WinForm** then use [`TextBox.ReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly.aspx) property.

Code would be same for both like:

```
if (textBox1.Text == "No")
{
    textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
}
```

See: [How to: Create a Read-Only Text Box (Windows Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byfd5ch8.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
textbox1.ReadOnly = true;
```

Or this:

```
textbox1.Enabled = false;
```